# Any way to undelete pull request comments?

Tags: github

Is there any way to restore a deleted comment in a Github pull request?

I can't see anything in the UI that allows you to do so, which would seem bad.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is currently no way that I know of to revive pull request comments or issue comments. It is a feature that needs to be implemented.

If you need this feature desperately, you can email them at support@github.com. They are usually very kind and helpful, and you might have your feature in no time!

In the meantime, just try commenting again.